# why useEffect hook not working as expected - how its related to useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, use-effect

I'm new to react hook, in `useEffect` I am creating on function, which will be called on clicking button inside the same component. But Im facing one prob, everytime its using one step old prop value, not new one.  Im not getting why.

And if I assign prop in state, it will work fine, even I'm not using state value, just setting.

[Try here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ekj9fg)

```
const defaultCalls = () => {
    let fn = (e) => console.log('This is default click fn.');
    return {
        overrideClickCall: (newFn) => {
            fn = newFn
        },
        clickFn: (e) => {
            fn(e);
        }
    }
}

let dCalls = defaultCalls();

const anotherFn = (e, userName) => {
  console.log(userName);
}

const MyComp = props => {
  let newFn = (e) => anotherFn(e, props.userName)

  //let [state, setState] = useState(props.userName);//on uncommenting it will work fine

  useEffect(() => {
    //setState(props.userName);  //on uncommenting it will work fine    
    dCalls = defaultCalls();
    dCalls.overrideClickCall(newFn);
    console.log('override default fn')
  }, [props.userName]);

  return (
    <input type="button" onClick={dCalls.clickFn} value="Click Me" />
  )
}

export { MyComp }
```

Comment: *"Try here"*  Please put your runnable example **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: That code looks very complicated for what you've said you're trying to do. What is the purpose of `defaultCalls`, `dCalls`, etc.? To just create a function that will get used as a click handler, you don't have to do anything special. If you want to, you can memoize it with `useCallback`, but usually that's not necessary. It seems like you're trying to do something more than just have a click handler...?

Comment: will put the snippet here it self soon, defaultCalls. lets say it 3rd party lib, doing some complex operation, and that has provided functionality of `overriding` also

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand what you mean in that comment.

Comment: consider `defaultCalls` is like a library I am using, and it provides a way so that you can override default `click` handler. that Im overriding in `useEffect` of my component.

Comment: I'm not following you... your code seems to be working fine for me. Every time I type somthing in the input it logs "useEffect called with..." to the console, and if I click on the button is logs whaterver is in the input. Isn't that what was expected? I didn't uncomment any line. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @julianobrasil on clicking the button notice the user name is one letter less than what you have typed in input box.  if you type `Hello` in input box, it will show `useEffect called with Hello`on console, but if you click button it will log `Hell`, not `Hello` pls try it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ekj9fg check image here https://imgur.com/WisBncT.png

Comment: Oh, now I got it. I'm gonna elaborate an answer to that and we can discuss it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's think of a snapshot. Whenever you have a property value, the component function is executed with the current props values (everything inside the function body that references any props is replaced with the actual prop value). After that initial setup of values, `useEffect` is executed. In your case, that means that this line:

```html
<input type="button" onClick={dCalls.clickFn} value="Click Me" />
```

is created before `useEffect` has run to update your `defaultCalls`. So it has an out-of-date copy of the `clickFn`.

How you can solve it: instead of `onClick={dCalls.clickFn}`, turn it into a function itself: `onClick={(e) => dCalls.clickFn(e)}`.

By doing that, you won't work with any memoized version of `clickFn` in the `onClick` event. It will grab the `clickFn` only when the user clicks on the button, and, as a consequence, the latest version of `clickFn`.

BTW, I really hope you're just doing some learning experiments because this code with so many indirections would be a footgun in the short term.

I strongly recommend this reading: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

It's not a short reading but I can count with the fingers of my hands how many times I've seen a so thorough explanation about a single topic in a developer article.

Comment: Thanks @julianobrasil that did the trick, in actual I understood my mistake. much appreciated. and yes I am just learning the hooks of react, so was trying it and got suck.